# Cannot debug Windows Phone Runtime Components with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I know I have to enable "Native Only" debug mode for the managed project when trying to debug C++ Windows Phone Runtime Components in a Windows Phone application. And I've ensured that I am building a Debug build.

Still, I get the error

```
The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document
```

And

```
...TestLib.winmd'. Module was built without symbols
```

I also cannot see any console output in the debugger console. This situation reminds me exactly of a situation where I would not have set the Debug mode to "Native Only" - but I have. I can see the .pdb file is being generated for the component, but it's not being added to the XAP file.

I have a Windows Phone Runtime Component project + a Windows Phone Unit Test App project in my solution. I am trying to debug the component project by running unit tests with "Debug Unit Tests".

And I am sure I have been able debug unit tests this way with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3. But I recently updated to Update 4, and since then I have not been able to debug my component in this solution via the Unit Test App.

Does anyone else have this kind of issues with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4? **Any help would be much appreciated!**

I created a bug about this to Microsoft. The bug report contains as an attachment a very simple test project show casing my scenario and demonstrating how it doesn't work (for me).

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809113/visual-studio-2012-express-update-4-stopped-generating-symbols-for-windows-phone-runtime-components-cannot-debug-runtime-components

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get solution to this?

Comment: No solution unfortunately. If you visit the link where I reported the issue to MSFT, you'll see that they confirmed the issue, but the bug is now closed as "Deferred". No solution in sight as of now at least.

Comment: After some months did you get any solution for this issue? I'm facing the same problem but with VS2013 Update 2 and 8.1 version. If you also have any clue useful for me, please check my ticket -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864344/debugging-a-windows-phone-8-1-unit-test-visual-c