# Debugging a Windows Phone 8.1 Unit test (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

The issue is that I have created an **Universal App** for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 choosing in the wizard Visual C++ -> Store Apps -> Universal Apps -> Windows Runtime Component.

So to test its behaviour we have created a **Windows Phone 8.1 Unit test** project (also Visual C++) where we add as reference the Universal App project, and also in the project properties in the tab Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General, in Additional include directories I referenced the Universal App (specifically the folder .Shared of the Universal App). Then we add also some .lib to this Unit test project through Configuration properties -> Link -> Input.

So this ok, the Unit test project find the references, and we can call methods from the Universal App even test them with assertions, and so on.

The issue is when I try to **debug** the Unit test code in the **ARM platform** (I have Nokia Lumia 920 plugged in the computer) it starts to load the microsoft symbols, etc. but finish the test without stopping or just terminate the test with an exception message (even passing the test or not).

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 2.

PS. In case of not being able to debug it due to any Microsoft and/or version issue or whatever, could I show in the console some values? Cause I also tried with std::cout, or OutputDebugString, without success.

PS2. My case reminds me to this issue descripted in this ticket but with a different version of Visual Studio and working with Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1 instead of 8 version ---> **[Cannot debug Windows Phone Runtime Components with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106099/cannot-debug-windows-phone-runtime-components-with-visual-studio-2012-update-4)**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding and selecting the .runsettings file as shown in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx) article. You can select the .runsettings file by using the guide on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) page under "Customizing tests with a .runsettings file". The app I used this technique on was also a WP 8.1 RT app.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing `Default Processor Architecture` to `x64` under Test > Test Settings